# Laravel 4.1 - Testing an Artisan command with Phpunit and Mockery

Tags: php, testing, laravel, mockery

I'm writing my first Artisan command in Laravel 4.1 and wanted to get some ideas on how to test it. My command does one thing (for now). It basically deletes table entries (Notes) from a DB that are a specified amount of days old.

---

**Command Example:**

```
OneTimeNote:delete --days=25
```

The command works with flying colors. But I've written the command first for learning purposes and now I desire to follow it with a test. I'm using PHPUnit and Mockery.

---

**Command Code:**
http://pastebin.com/index/dZrxpt8x

As you can see, I'm injecting my Note implementation (for abstraction) and then I'm executing one of it's methods 'deleteNotesOlderThan(int $days)'. Like I said, this all works fine and dandy. My issue starts when I'm trying to test the thing.

---

**Command Test**: http://pastebin.com/6UwxGvcN

If you look at the code, you can see where I'm stuck at. How do I Mock my Note method and generate a Command Test? Also what sort of things should I be testing with this particular command?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestion would be to follow the examples given for you in Laravel.

Picking a random artisan test from the framework, it looks like you don't need Symfony's 'CommandTester' class, but instead you just instantiate and go.

From https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/tests/Foundation/FoundationConfigPublishCommandTest.php: (link subject to become stale)

```
public function testCommandCallsPublisherWithProperPackageName()
{
    $command = new Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigPublishCommand($pub = m::mock('Illuminate\Foundation\ConfigPublisher'));
    $pub->shouldReceive('publishPackage')->once()->with('foo');
    $command->run(new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput(array('package' => 'foo')), new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput);
}
```

So you instantiate your command, passing in your mocked repository interface, add your expectations to the mock, then call `run` on the command, passing in 'fake' input and output classes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I went ahead and did as you suggested but with the added functionality of Symfony's CommandTester tools. Do you have any suggestions on what I should test with my particular command?

Comment: You'll notice that, in general, the commands in Laravel don't do a lot. They defer their *actual* functionality to business logic classes that do the hard work. If you're serious about your code design and testing, you should follow the same path. Your command should merely parse the command line arguments and pass it all on. That class should be tested so that it does what it should. In your case it could be argued that the repository is this additional business logic class, so you may simply want to ensure that its `deleteNotesOlderThan` method is called with the right arguments.

Comment: Obviously, after that, you should ensure that the repository is fully tested too, in that case you'll want to ensure that, for a given non-mocked instance of the repository, calling `deleteNotesOlderThan` with various inputs does the right stuff. It's way too easy to people to accidentally test too much of hat a method does and not of what it produces when it comes to mocking, even the Laravel codebase can be guilty of this sometimes. Have a read of my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21752195/1551393) for more info. I'm no testing expert though, so do what you want with my advice.