# How to test repository pattern in a good way with Laravel

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, repository-pattern

So I'm quite inexperienced with testing but I'm working on it. One of the things I read was that a test should not really care how the method does what it does but check the expected outcome.

With this in mind, I'm not sure if I'm testing my repositories in a useful manner. As I read in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743467/testing-chained-method-call-in-mockery) the way I'm doing it, is actually almost writing the code twice.

Consider the following code:

```
public function getUserCart($userId)
{
    return $this->shoppingcarts->whereUserId($userId)->first();
}
```

With the following test:

```
public function testGetUserCart()
{
    $shoppingcartMock = $this->mock('Shoppingcart');

    $shoppingcartMock->shouldReceive('whereUserId')->once()->with('some id')->andReturn($shoppingcartMock);
    $shoppingcartMock->shouldReceive('first')->once()->andReturn('cart');

    $repo = App::make('EloquentShoppingcartRepository');

    $this->assertEquals('cart', $repo->getUserCart('some id'));
}
```

My test passes and I have code coverage but if I were to change `$this->shoppingcarts->whereUserId($userId)->first()` with `$this->shoppingcarts->where('user_id', $userId)->first()` the test fails of course.

The code performs just the same and in my opinion a good test should not really care what exact method i'm using as long as the outcome is as expected.

My question is twofold. Is it useful to test repositories? And if so, what approach should I take?