# PHPUnit mock concatenated function

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I am writing some test and I was wondering how I could mock the next concatenated funciton call:

```
$validator->errors()->all()
```

I do not need the errors collection, as I want it to be emmpty so that `$this->logerror` isn't called.

Is it possible to mock the `$validator->errors()->all()` in one call ?

Something like

```
    Validator::shouldReceive('errors()->all()')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(array());
```

---

```
Code:
// CLASS

    $validator = Validator::make(
            ['participant' => $participant'],
            $programValidator->getRules()
    );

    if($validator->fails()) {
        foreach($validator->errors()->all() as $error) {
           $this->logError($record, $error);
    }
```

---

```
// TEST
Validator::shouldReceive('make')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(Mockery::mock(array('fails' => true)));
```

Comment: you must mock all the methods call, so you must muck that the call for method `errors()` should return an also mocked object that in the `all()` method call return an empty array. For a complete answer you need to specify which  framework and the version you use, at least which object type is returned at the call of the call method. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Validator::shouldReceive('errors->all')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn(array());
```

This answer might also be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22435748/5072503